# db2ilist shows the instance, but db2idrop says instance doesn't exists

Tags: db2, db2-luw

/opt/IBM/db2_10_01/bin/db2ilist shows the instance db2inst1 exists. But, when I try to drop it using /opt/IBM/db2_10_01/instance/db2idrop it gives error:

The specified instance "db2inst1" does not exist. Specify an existing instance
name.

How to drop instance in such scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when Db2-instance removal was incorrectly performed, often if directories were manually removed or mount points unavailable etc.

To recover, study this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/r0020699.html) until you comprehend it.

Become root and run

`db2greg -dump`

Study its output carefully and ensure you comprehend the output (read the documentation carefully).

You may see the line that identifies the db2inst1 - so carefully verify that each detail matches your expectation and the documentation.

Take a secure backup of the global-registry-file. This is a vital step.

As root, run db2greg without any arguments and study the instructions. Your aim is to run db2greg -delinstrec with some additional options to identify the line to delete, via a comma-separated list of field=value tokens.
For example `db2greg -delinstrec instancename=db2inst1,instancepath=...` etc.

When db2greg -delinstrec completes successfully (it takes a couple of seconds), you can then run db2ilist and you should find that db2inst1 has disappeared.